# how to handle merge conflicts in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have following problem with gitlab-ci: my jobs execute perfectly fine everything works as expected except when i have merge conflicts. Is there any effective way to handle merge conflicts in gitlab-ci and not trigger pipelines until the conflict get solved ???
here is a sample pipeline which could trigger merge conflict:

```
image: alpine:latest
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^(dev)$/ || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ /^(web)/

stages:
- build
build software:
  stage: build
  script:
  - printenv
  - echo "Building code for $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
```

I appreciate any suggestion. Thank you :)